# how dynamically update fragment view

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-fragments

I have to implement an application for my university and I need some advice from an expert :) . I have an activity that use `PageIndicator`, every page is a fragment. Max one page is currently displayed. In every fragment there are 4 widget that contains a value read from application via Bluetooth (there is a serial device that send data via Bluetooth to the application) I think that my activity must have a independent thread that in a loop communicate with the serial devices. But when this thread reads value, how can send the data to the current fragment, in particular to the specified widget? the current widget must show most recent data read. In other words i need to know how a thread of activity can send a dato to the current fragment .
sorry for my english

Comment: "I have to implement and hard application" -> not sure what "and hard application" stands for

Answer (score 5, accepted):

while creating the fragments, record them in an ArrayList and create a custom fragment class that extends Fragment

```
static public ArrayList<CustomFragment> fragmentsList = new ArrayList<CustomFragment>();

// create new fragment
// Example:
// CustomFragment myFragment = new FragmentOne();

fragmentsList.add(newlyCreatedFragment);
```

and inside the fragment create a method to receive the updates, for example

your fragment class:

```
public class CustomFragment extends Fragment {

    public void receiveUpdate(String update) {
      // Do something
    }
}
```

then instead of "extends Fragment" use "extends CustomFragment"

then from other classes

```
CustomFragment theFragment = SomeClass.fragmentsList.get(0); // where 0 is the fragment's index
theFragment.receiveUpdate("the update");
```

Comment: but who invoke theFragment.receiveUpdate("the update") ? and i dont understand why extends CustomFragment

Comment: you have to create a custom fragment to create "receiveUpdate" method and then call it from other classes to update the fragment.

then you will have to override receiveUpdate method in each fragment and handle the updates.

Comment: ok but he call receeive update ? the reader thread or the reader thread pass the value read to the activity?

Comment: but the thread comunicate the reads value to the activity by broadcastreceiver installated in activity and then the activity call update method of fragment ?

Comment: Yes, whenever you want to update the fragment, call receiveUpdate method and you can create other methods, like how it is in the last code in my answer.