# update android fragment contents view.invalidate()

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-view, android-adapter

I have a simple fragment inside of an activity, and i need it to update its contents.

I have the handle to the root views, but

```
view.invalidate()
```

does'nt do anything.

When I pop the fragment off the back-stack and push it again, then it updates it contents.
Is this the way to update the fragment.

Comment: This is one way, but you could also handle the update by an own method. Look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12238421/how-dynamically-update-fragment-view